# Folder Permission/Security issue using Persistent Live Ubuntu?

Tags: live-usb

Using Ubuntu 18.04 with latest updates on laptop.

A guest user with a standard account on a Ubuntu-persistent USB drive has access to the laptop installed file system. Surely this should not be allowable?

Permissions on the user account installed file system are set for "Others" to "None" and for all folders and files within.

Booting from a Live Ubuntu USB with Persistence, to a Guest Standard account, all the computer folders are visible with a padlock and X in grey but all the contents are accessible, that is, they are not locked to an outsider.

What is happening here, and should it be allowed?

How can I get greater security for the installed file system?

Many thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This is the normal behaviour. One way to use a live or persistent live drive to repair an installed system or extract files from a damaged system. And it is at least as easy to get access to a healthy installed system ;-)
- If you don't want this, you can install Ubuntu with 'encrypted disk' alias LVM with LUKS encryption. Then the guests, who use a [persistent] live drive can see the encrypted container, but they need the passphrase to unlock it.

  You need good backups with an encrypted system, because it is much more difficult to repair it and to extract files from it.

Comment: Thanks for that sudodus. I understand what you are saying, but I don't understand why access isn't limited in this sort of example, since, presumably, that is the purpose of varied permissions. And can you give an example of what the permission "Others" would actually be? To me it sounds like a catch-all for 'not known'.

Comment: In general, physical access to a computer, means access to the data. Normal users will be stopped by 'encrypted disk', but a professional intruder can mount a keylogger or 'evil maid' or use some other method, that makes you reveal how to log in, next time you come to the computer. The classic protection via ownership and permissions works, when there is not physical access (and people log in via a network). -- You could turn off booting from a USB drive, but a knowledgeable friend or colleague might be able to modify the settings unless you lock the UEFI/BIOS menus with a password.

Comment: OK, sudodus, I am with you now. Thanks for your input.